# Running emacs from the command line and handling locked files

Tags: emacs, command-line, org-mode

I'm using org-mode and am looking to export my agenda ([example of an agenda](http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/daily_plan.png)) to a text file so that I can display it with conky. The [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-agenda-information.html#Extracting-agenda-information) features this command line example to do this:

```
emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs -eval '(org-batch-agenda "t")' | lpr
```

I've modified this like so:

```
emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs -eval '(org-batch-agenda "e")' \
> ~/org/aux/agenda-export.txt
```

I have this set as a cron job to run every 5 minutes. It works great unless I actually have emacs open. Then I noticed that the file `agenda-export.txt` was empty. In running this manually from the coammand line vs. through cron, I get this error (or similar depending on the files I have open):

```
...~/org/file.org locked by jwhendy (pid 10935): (s, q, p, ?)?
```

I was going to write a script to perhaps export to `agenda-export-test.txt`, then perhaps check for an empty file or no lines (`wc -l == 0` maybe?). If true, leave the existing file alone and delete `agenda-export-test.txt`. If not, then move `agenda-export-test.txt` to `agenda-export.txt`.

But... when I try to run such a script, I'm met with the same emacs inquiry about whether to steal the lock, proceed, or quit. I'm fine with proceeding, as I don't think org-agenda does anything to the files and thus it wouldn't harm anything... but I don't know how to tell emacs to "force" or choose "proceed" if problems are encountered. I need something non-interactive.

So, to summarize, my thoughts were to try:

- passing a --force option or similar to emacs to make it proceed at the pause
- see if the exported tmp file has any lines and deal with it accordingly
- tell emacs to run in "read only mode" (but I don't think it exists)

The main issue is that with cron, I'm not there to tell the process what to do, and so it just just make an empty file as the exported results. How can I handle this locked file business with a "blind" process like cron that can't respond?

I've tried asking the mailing list as well without a working outcome. [1] I wondered if someone here might have ideas.

[1] http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg45056.html

Comment: Tangential remark on the uselessness of using `wc -l` to test for an empty file.  `man test` (specifically `test -s`) or perhaps `grep` if you want to look for non-empty lines or something.

Comment: @tripleee: thanks. I'm no bash expert by any stretch of the imagination. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried copying file without using emacs?
put in your crontab:

```
cp ~/org/file.org /tmp/export.org && emacs -batch .... /tmp/export.org ..
```

A regular "cp" command should not copy emacs locks. Of course, once in a while you might get a damaged file if you save agenda just during cp command, but this should not be too bad.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I have a couple questions: 1) org-mode gets its list for agenda candidates from .emacs; thus I think I'd need a separate .emacs file to tell it to look in /tmp/dir/ vs. ~/org. 2) On that note, I'd need to copy a dir every time, as I have about 10 files being pulled from, not just one. That might have been confusing in my question -- I was giving an example of what the lock complaint looks like. If I have several open, I get an error for each.

Comment: 1) Not really. The third example in the "org-mode" manual you referenced shows how to change file location. You can define function in main .emacs and call it from command line to make command line shorter. 2) No problem, 'mkdir -p /tmp/dest && cp dir/*.org /tmp/dest/' would happily copy multiple files. If your files are big (300K+), you can use rsync, but I think this will be overkill.

Comment: I just lived with this for a while by having the cron job not run if emacs was open. I got frustrated enough at lack of updates to revisit this and your solution definitely works! I adjusted my simple bash script to check for /tmp/org; if it doesn't exist, create it. Then cp ~/org/*.org /tmp/org/. Then run the command above, but with the (as you pointed out!) `org-agenda-files (quote ("/tmp/org"))` option. Works wonderfully.